# How do I automatically bind a string array to a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` inside of a `UserControl`. It looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExternalDataSourceComparison.ImportedInfoGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="_dataGrid" Grid.Row="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path[0].Length}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I have the `UserControl` in my `MainWindow` that looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ExternalDataSourceComparison.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExternalDataSourceComparison"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:ImportedInfoGrid x:Name="ExternalData" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <StackPanel Height="36px" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Name="_import" Content="Import Data" Margin="5" Padding="5, 2" Click="Import_Click"/>
        <Button Name="_compare" Content="Compare" Margin="5" Padding="5, 2" Click="Compare_Click"/>
        <Button Name="_cancel" Content="Cancel" Margin="5" Padding="5, 2" Click="Cancel_Click"/>            
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In my code behind for the window using the method `fs.CSVToStringArray`, I open up a CSV file and parse out the contents to a `string[][]` the outer array represents the rows and the inner array are all of the columns so string[0][3] would be row 1 column 4.

In my code behind I just set `ItemsSource` equal to the array of arrays as shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;

namespace ExternalDataSourceComparison
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        FileStuff fs = new FileStuff();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Import_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[][] array = fs.CSVToStringArray();
            this.ExternalData._dataGrid.ItemsSource = array;
        }

        private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Compare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The output is not what I expected at all though. I think it showing the attributes of the object instead of the actual content. Is there a way to automatically generate rows and columns or will I have to write the code to create the columns and build the rows? I thought with a `DataGrid` you could bind something like a `string[][]` or a `List<string[]>` to the `ItemsSource` and it would just generated columns. It is currently automatically generating columns, it just isn't filling them with the contents of the `string[][]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`DataGrid`'s auto-generate columns feature isn't quite suitable for displaying jagged array data. It is better suited for single, one-dimentional collection where each row in `DataGrid` represent single item in collection, and each column represent different property of corresponding item.

And unless the item in `ItemsSource` is a model that is ready for display, you shouldn't rely on auto-generate columns feature (it will display column for all properties, including those properties not meant to be displayed). Another issue when trying to *automagically* bind `DataGrid` to array is, `DataGrid` doesn't have information on how it should name the column.

In the end, I think you better define `DataGrid` columns somehow, instead of letting `DataGrid` it self generate the columns. Either define it from XAML, for example, assuming you always have two "columns" in the array :

```
<DataGrid Name="_dataGrid" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Binding="{Binding [0]}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Binding="{Binding [1]}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Or define the columns from code, in case you have dynamic number of columns, for example :

```
string[][] array = fs.CSVToStringArray();
for (int i = 0; i < array[0].Length; i++)
{
    var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
    col.Header = "Column " + i;
    col.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", i));
    _dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
}
this.ExternalData._dataGrid.ItemsSource = array;
```