# How to fill a DataGrid from String Array?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

So I'm currently creating a C# WPF application with a DataGrid to show the user some strings he entered before.
I'm pretty new to WPF and programming in general so I have no clue where to begin.
My problem is that I don't know how to fill data in the DataGrid. This could be a duplicate but as there aren't simple tutorials for beginners I would be happy about some help.

I currently have an ArrayList userInput filled with strings:

```
userInput{"the", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"}
```

This is the result I want to achieve:

```
(1) the   | brown
(2) fox   | jumps
(3) over  | the
(4) lazy  | dog
```

I did some research and I found something named data-binding but I don't really understand how it works. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922533/how-do-i-automagically-bind-a-string-array-to-a-wpf-datagrid

Comment: Create a model, fill a list of model with data, bind this list to datagrid

Comment: @snnbrn I found that post already but I don't understand how it works. I'm really a beginner thats the main problem why I asked that question...

Comment: Read this first: [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest the solution for you in a simpler way. you must have schema first. simply need to convert your array list to an CustomClass list

```
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }




  public List<User> users = new List<User>();

  users.Add(new User() { Name = "dogs" });
  users.Add(new User() { Name = "dog" });
  users.Add(new User() { Name = "cat" });
  users.Add(new User() { Name = "cats" });


 this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = users;

  <DataGrid Height="179" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,65,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="382">
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: When I use the code, I only get empty rows. Do I have to specify first, that the DataGrid shows the Name?

Comment: Got it. Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!