# How to bind "DataGrid.Items" with ObservableCollection<SomeType[]>?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, datagrid, avaloniaui

I am looking for way to bind Avalonia `DataGrid.Items` with `ObservableCollection<SomeType[]>` collection. So, row is array of `SomeType[]` where every element is value for `DataGrid` cell. Is it possible? Now it binding fields of class **Array** instead of binding elements and I know, it is a usual way. But I need to do it dynamically when I don't know how many columns it can take. Like `DataTable.DefaultView` and `DataGrid` in .NET.

In my XAML it look like this:

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Items="{Binding Rows}"/>
```

where `Rows` is `ObservableCollection<string[]> Rows { get; set; }` inside my view model.

Comment: Why don't you introduce a domain object?

Comment: @PeterCsala, I'm not sure I got what did you mean. Could you rephrase?

Comment: I suggested to create a model  where you map each of the strings of your array to a property of a `class` or `struct`. So, instead of having `ObservableCollection<string[]>` you should have `ObservableCollection<DomainObject>`

Comment: @PeterCsala, I try to use array instead of domain object, because the properties(array items in my case) count is unknown and can be any one. It depends what table user choose and how many columns it have. It can be 3 or 15 or 1000 columns in a table. So I looking for way to change number of grid column dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: You can't do that via `AutoGenerateColumns`.

Let's suppose I've this simplified UI:

```xml
<Window x:Class="_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Grid"></DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then If I specify the `Grid`'s `ItemsSource` like this:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var dataSource = new ObservableCollection<string[]>
    {
        new []{ "A", "B", "C"},
        new []{ "C", "B", "A"},
    };
    Grid.ItemsSource = dataSource;
}
```

Then I would see the following result:

[image: Arrays' properties are showed]

So, it shows the arrays' properties instead of their content.

---

In order to list their content you need to manually add the columns to the `Grid`:

```cs
foreach (var idx in dataSource[0].Select((value, index) => index))
{
    Grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = $"{idx + 1}. column", Binding = new Binding($"[{idx}]") });
}
```

Let's put everything together:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var dataSource = new ObservableCollection<string[]>
    {
        new []{ "A", "B", "C"},
        new []{ "C", "B", "A"},
    };

    foreach (var idx in dataSource[0].Select((value, index) => index))
    {
        Grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = $"{idx + 1}. column", Binding = new Binding($"[{idx}]") });
    }

    Grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    Grid.ItemsSource = dataSource;
}
```

and the result will be:
[image: Arrays' content are showed]

[Credit goes to har07](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22928980/13268855)

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me(on Avalonia by the way). Thank you!